# Is there any way to change locale along with currency for admin in Magento2

Tags: admin, currency, magento2.1.6, locale, switcher

I want to update the currency and the rates for admin based on the user for which locale is set. For eg., if the locale is French, the currency should be French, but if the user is logged in from US locale it should be USD. The areas which I am referring to are, Dashboard, Orders grid/view, Products grid view.

[image]

Comment: Single store, multiple store views, single website

Comment: Updated question with screenshot

Comment: Do you have any option to set locale per user?

Comment: Yes it is default!

Comment: When you create a new admin user, there is an option in admin to choose locale. I repeat I am referring to admin interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved by doing some customisation.

1. Add a currency drop-down in add/edit user form at admin.
2. Add and admin event observe for

> contoller_action_predispatch

Then in this observer get selected currency for current admin and apply that currency to store manager object.

So this will be applicable for all admin pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can change locale from admin under `System -> Configuration -> General` and currency from `System -> Configuration -> Currency setup`